# GDB: Listing all mapped memory regions for a crashed process

Tags: linux, gdb

I've got a full-heap core dump from a dead process on an x86 Linux machine (kernel 2.6.35-22 if it matters), which I'm attempting to debug in GDB.

Is there a GDB command I can use that means "show me a list of all the memory address regions allocated by this process?" In other words, can I figure out what all the possible valid memory addresses are that I can examine in this dump?

The reason I ask is that I need to search across the *entire process heap* for a certain binary string, and in order to use the `find` command, I need to have a start and end address. Simply searching from 0x00 to 0xff.. doesn't work because `find` halts as soon as it encounters an address it can't access:

> (gdb) find /w 0x10000000, 0xff000000,
>   0x12345678
>
> warning: Unable to access target memory at 0x105ef883, halting
>   search.

So I need to get a list of all the readable address regions in memory so I can search them one at a time.

(The reason I need to do *that* is I need to find all the structs in memory that point *at* a certain address.)

None of `show mem`, `show proc`, `info mem`, `info proc` seem to do what I need.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

In GDB 7.2:

```
(gdb) help info proc
Show /proc process information about any running process.
Specify any process id, or use the program being debugged by default.
Specify any of the following keywords for detailed info:
  mappings -- list of mapped memory regions.
  stat     -- list a bunch of random process info.
  status   -- list a different bunch of random process info.
  all      -- list all available /proc info.
```

You want `info proc mappings`, except it doesn't work when there is no `/proc` (such as during pos-mortem debugging).

Try `maintenance info sections` instead.

Comment: That's one of the first things I tried, but it seems to be empty (there's nothing under the header row). Maybe it just doesn't work for core dumps?

Comment: `maintenance info sections` seems to be way more portable and should be the primary answer here.

Comment: If you're debugging a live process, you can also get/verify this information from `cat /proc/<pid>/maps`

Comment: @phihag That was [converted to an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23231859). Redundant comment now.

Comment: `info proc mappings` worked for me. The PWNDGB version is `vmmaps`.

Answer (score 24):

If you have the program and the core file, you can do the following steps.

1) Run the gdb on the program along with core file

```
 $gdb ./test core
```

2) type info files and see what different segments are there in the core file.

```
    (gdb)info files
```

A sample output:

```
    (gdb)info files 

    Symbols from "/home/emntech/debugging/test".
    Local core dump file:
`/home/emntech/debugging/core', file type elf32-i386.
  0x0055f000 - 0x0055f000 is load1
  0x0057b000 - 0x0057c000 is load2
  0x0057c000 - 0x0057d000 is load3
  0x00746000 - 0x00747000 is load4
  0x00c86000 - 0x00c86000 is load5
  0x00de0000 - 0x00de0000 is load6
  0x00de1000 - 0x00de3000 is load7
  0x00de3000 - 0x00de4000 is load8
  0x00de4000 - 0x00de7000 is load9
  0x08048000 - 0x08048000 is load10
  0x08049000 - 0x0804a000 is load11
  0x0804a000 - 0x0804b000 is load12
  0xb77b9000 - 0xb77ba000 is load13
  0xb77cc000 - 0xb77ce000 is load14
  0xbf91d000 - 0xbf93f000 is load15
```

In my case I have 15 segments. Each segment has start of the address and end of the address. Choose any segment to search data for. For example lets select load11 and search for a pattern. Load11 has start address 0x08049000 and ends at 0x804a000.

3) Search for a pattern in the segment.

```
(gdb) find /w 0x08049000 0x0804a000 0x8048034
 0x804903c
 0x8049040
 2 patterns found
```

If you don't have executable file you need to use a program which prints data of all segments of a core file. Then you can search for a particular data at an address. I don't find any program as such, you can use the program at the following link which prints data of all segments of a core or an executable file.

```
 http://emntech.com/programs/printseg.c
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get gdb to search all of these segments without manually specifying each?

Comment: That printseg.c is no longer on that website. It is also not available on archive.org

Answer (score 11):

```
(gdb) maintenance info sections 
Exec file:
    `/path/to/app.out', file type elf32-littlearm.
    0x0000->0x0360 at 0x00008000: .intvecs ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
```

This is from comment by phihag above, deserves a separate answer. This works but `info proc` does not on the arm-none-eabi-gdb v7.4.1.20130913-cvs from the gcc-arm-none-eabi Ubuntu package.

Comment: This will show mappings that come from the executable or libraries, but not things like the stack of a user-space process.  But yes, in a core dump, that may be the best you can do, if the core dump doesn't record info from `/proc/<pid>/maps`.

Comment: @PeterCordes The core file has to store heap and stacks, otherwise it would be fairly useless. In ELF core files, they are stored as segments, and for me (elf64-x86-64), `maintenance info sections` lists those just fine.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `info files` to list all the sections of all the binaries loaded in process binary.

Answer (score 5):

I have just seen the following:

```
set mem inaccessible-by-default [on|off]
```

[here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory-Region-Attributes.html#Memory-Region-Attributes)

It might allow you to search without regard if the memory is accessible.

Comment: Hm, for me on GDB 10.1 this does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: @Gizmo Was that on x86? The link still describes this as it should work.

Comment: Yes, debugging a x86 target.

Answer (score 2):

Note that none of these will help you if you want to identify where the process had shared-memory segments, `mmap()`ed regions, etc mapped into its address space.

This info doesn't seem to be included in the core. Neither `maintenance info target-sections` nor `maintenance info target` show it.

(So it probably just doesn't exist, or at best is in a core section gdb doesn't use. It might be possible to figure some out from internal libc book-keeping state, but not in a generic way).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `maintenance info sections` is that command tries to extract information from the section header of the binary. It does not work if the binary is tripped (e.g by `sstrip`) or it gives wrong information when the loader may change the memory permission after loading (e.g. the case of `RELRO`).

Comment: `info proc mappings` is not available when debugging a core dump.

Comment: Ahhh, you are correct, `info proc mappings` does not apply in this case.