# post-mortem memory leak search (and analysis) with gdb

Tags: c, linux, gdb

My goal altogether is to figure out from a post mortem core file, why a specific process is consuming a lot of memory. Is there a summary that I can get somehow? As obvious valgrind is out of the question, because I can't get access to the process live.

First of all getting an output something similar to /proc/"pid"/maps, would help, but

```
maintenance info sections
```

(as described here: [GDB: Listing all mapped memory regions for a crashed process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691193/gdb-listing-all-mapped-memory-regions-for-a-crashed-process)) in gdb didn't show me heap memory consumption.

```
info proc map
```

is an option, as I can get access to machine with the exact same code, but as far as I have seen it is not correct. My process was using 700MB-s, but the maps seen only accounted for some 10 MBs. And I didn't see .so-s there which are visible in

```
maintenance print statistics
```

Do you know any other command which might be useful?

I can always instrument the code, but that's no easy. Along with reaching all the allocated data through pointers is like needle in the haystack.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postmortem debugging of this sort in gdb is a bit of an art more than a science.

The most important tool for it, in my opinion, is the ability to write scripts that run inside of gdb. The manual will explain it to you. The reason I find this so useful is that it lets you do things like walking data structures and printing out information abou them.

Another possibility for you here is to instrument your version of malloc -- write a new malloc function that saves statistics about what is being allocated so that you can then look at those post mortem. You can, of course, call the original malloc to do the actual memory allocation work.

I'm sorry that I can't give you an obvious and simple answer that will simply yield an immediate fix for you here -- without tools like valgrind this is a very hard job.

Comment: I should look into scripting then. Walking data structures is a big help.

Answer (score 2):

If its Linux you dont have to worry about doing stats to your malloc.  Use the utility called 'memusage'

for a sample program (sample_mem.c) like below

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(voiid)
{
        int i=1000;
        char *buff=NULL;
        srand(time(NULL));

        while(i--)
        {
                buff = malloc(rand() % 64);
                free(buff);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

the output of memusage will be

```
$memusage sample_mem

Memory usage summary: heap total: 31434, heap peak: 63, stack peak: 80
         total calls   total memory   failed calls
 malloc|       1000          31434              0
realloc|          0              0              0  (nomove:0, dec:0, free:0)
 calloc|          0              0              0
   free|       1000          31434
Histogram for block sizes:
    0-15            253  25% ==================================================
   16-31            253  25% ==================================================
   32-47            247  24% ================================================
   48-63            247  24% ================================================
```

but if your writing a malloc wapper then you can make your program coredump after this many number of malloc so that you can get a clue.

Comment: Good idea. It took me some time to figure out, but memusage is part of glibc release. However this is again a bit similar to run my code in valgrind, though with much smaller overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a simple tool like [log-malloc.c](http://brokestream.com/log-malloc.c) which compiles into a shared library which is `LD_PRELOAD`ed before your application and logs all the `malloc`-type functions to a file.  At least it might help narrow down the search in your dump.

Comment: Are you aware of any 64-bit log malloc?