# Get the list of pages used by a process

Tags: linux, x86, 64-bit, paging

How do I get a list of pages used by a process given its PID ? For each page, I would like to know its starting adress (should end with with 12*0 bits since pages are 4KB ?), and if it is writable/executable. A GDB-based solution would be nice too since i'm using it to debug.

Comment: `info proc mappings` is what you're looking for: [GDB: Listing all mapped memory regions for a crashed process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691193/gdb-listing-all-mapped-memory-regions-for-a-crashed-process)

Comment: Linux shows it in terms of extents, not listing each page separately in a single multi-page mapping.  Using `/proc/<PID>/smaps`, you can see how much of the region is using  transparent hugepages for anonymous mappings (actually 2M largepages, usually not 1G hugepages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping of the virtual memory pages of a process from its pid is visible in the /proc filesystem, described in man proc(5) : The pseudo file maps should be enough, the pseudo file smaps shows more details.

```
cat /proc/[pid]/maps
cat /proc/[pid]/smaps
```